# How to increase speed string processing in bash script?

Tags: linux, string, bash

I have string content as TXT file = 70 kb.
I want to find and cut string with pattern.

Sample content.

```
"<div jsname="Rfh2Tc" class="SL4Sz" id="i3" role="alert"></div></div></div></div><div class="Qr7Oae" role="listitem"><div jsmodel="CP1oW" data-params="%.@.[1696921474,&quot;พื้นที่&quot;,null,2,[[TARGET_STRING,[[&quot;BKK"
```

I use this code in bash script.

```
DATA=`cat content.txt`
DATA=${DATA##*พื้นที่&quot}
DATA=${DATA%\,\[\[*}
echo $DATA
```

It's work. But!
When it run, It very slow for 60++KB text file. and high CPU usage.
How can I fix it, Please help me.

Comment: If speed is a concern, you shouldn't be using `bash` as the scripting language in the first place.

Comment: How can i transfer this code to another language?

Comment: You can use a regular expression: `frontPattern:\[(.*)\]:BackPattern`

Comment: What language do you mean? C++?

Comment: Practically any language: C, C++, Python, PHP, Ruby. `bash` is the worst for serious programming.

Comment: please update the question with a) a sample of your input file (5-10 lines should suffice), b) the code you're currently using to parse the file and extract the desired data and c) the (correct) expected output; *NOTE:* I'm assuming your script already outputs the correct results otherwise also update the question with the (wrong) output generated by your code

Comment: Can you make sample C++ script ,Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sed`:

```
DATA=$( sed 's/.*FrontPattern:\[\(.*\?\)\]:BackPattern.*/\1/' <<< "$DATA" )
```

For a 70 KiB text file, this takes less than 20 ms on my machine.

Comment: It's not work for me. echo $DATA = full string data.

Comment: I updated the answer so that the input text is expected in the `DATA` variable.

Comment: You are a very nice man. (0o0 )!! Now I can speed it up.